# Does spin_lock_bh disable threaded interrupts?

Tags: linux, interrupt

If a threaded interrupt was created by using request_threaded_irq, and a call to spin_lock_bh is made in user context (read/write/ioctl, etc), can the threaded irq run while inside the spin_lock_bh?

spin_lock_bh documentation appears to say that bottom halves will be disabled on current cpu.  will it also disable threaded interrupts?

If so, will it disable the threaded interrupt from running on ALL cpus/cores?

Comment: The _bh part will prevent the interrupt from being serviced in the current CPU, the spin_lock will prevent it from being run on other CPUs using the same spinlock. spin_lock_bh also disables preemption.